# React Native how to export API response

Tags: react-native, api

how to export API response to another components?
i have axios that bring data from the back-end to the front-end, can i export the response data to another component/screen or i have to do Fetch/axios on each part i want render data on it

i have the API response on Home page, so i can export the data

**Home.js**

```
.....
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [ChartData, setChartData] = useState([]);
  const [BalanceData, setBalanceData] = useState([]);
  const [ExpensesData, setExpensesData] = useState([]);
  const [SavingsData, setSavingsData] = useState([]);
  const [IncomeData, setIncomeData] = useState([]);
  const [LoansData, setLoansData] = useState([]);


  const getData = () => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
    setChartData(response.data);
    let data = response.data;
    let balance =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "BALANCE"
    });

    setBalanceData(balance)

    let savings =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "SAVING"
    })

    setSavingsData(savings);

    let loans =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "LOANS"
    });
    setLoansData(loans);

    let income =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "INCOME"
    });
    setIncomeData(income);

    let expenses =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "EXPENSES"
    })

    setExpensesData(expenses);

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [])



    console.log("Chart Data", ChartData);
...
...
export default Home;
```

Comment: Pass it as a property to your other component(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario it is usually a good idea to encapsulate your business logic in a custom `hook` which you can then reuse in every functional component. This could look as follows.

```js
export const useMyBackendApi = () => {

  const [ChartData, setChartData] = useState([]);
  const [BalanceData, setBalanceData] = useState([]);
  const [ExpensesData, setExpensesData] = useState([]);
  const [SavingsData, setSavingsData] = useState([]);
  const [IncomeData, setIncomeData] = useState([]);
  const [LoansData, setLoansData] = useState([]);


  const getData = () => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
    setChartData(response.data);
    let data = response.data;
    let balance =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "BALANCE"
    });

    setBalanceData(balance)

    let savings =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "SAVING"
    })

    setSavingsData(savings);

    let loans =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "LOANS"
    });
    setLoansData(loans);

    let income =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "INCOME"
    });
    setIncomeData(income);

    let expenses =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "EXPENSES"
    })

    setExpensesData(expenses);

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [])

  return {
    ChartData,
    BalanceData,
    ExpenseData,
    SavingsData,
    IncomeData,
    LoansData,
  }
}
```

The in your Screen, you can use your hook.

```js
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { ChartData, BalanceData } = useMyBackendApi() // destructure whatever you need from your hook

    ...

    // do whatever
}
```

You can do the same in any other functional component.

It might be a good idea to `cache` your server response in order to prevent unwanted refetches. This could be done using [SWR Hooks](https://swr.vercel.app/). This could be used as follows in your scenario.

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'

export const useMyBackendApi = () => {

  // first param is your cache key, second param your fetcher
  const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR("http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/", (url) => {
    return axios.get('http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/')
  .then(function (response) {
   
    let data = response.data;
    let balance =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "BALANCE"
    });

    let savings =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "SAVING"
    })

    let loans =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "LOANS"
    });
    
    let income =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "INCOME"
    });
    
    let expenses =  data?.filter((vl) => {
      return vl?.type == "EXPENSES"
    })
    
    return {
        chartData: response.data,
        balanceData: balance,
        savingsData: savings,
        loansData: loans,
        incomeData: income,
        expensesData: expenses 
    } 
  })
    
 })

 const refresh = React.useCallback(() => {
     return mutate()
 }, [mutate])

  return {
    data,
    refresh,
    error
  }
}
```

Your data is now cached using `swr` hooks and your buisness logic is encapsulated in a custom hook. You can reuse this in every screen as follows.

```js
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {

   const {data} = useMyBackendApi()

   console.log(data.incomeData)
}
```

The procedure is the same in any other screen. Notice, that your data will not be refetched unless you trigger a `mutate` of your cache using the mutate function of swr. However, you could make the use of dependent cache keys for more complex situations.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the answer, it helped me a lot.